# How do I create an interactive daemon login?

Tags: linux, debian, login, user-management, daemon

I run a service on a debian/linux machine which runs at boot with a 'screen' session I can always attach to.

I would like to create a username which I can run this service as. At the moment I use a 'regular' login account. I would like the added security of a username dedicated to this sevrice (similar to the way 'nobody' or 'web' are used with apache).

Requirements:

- No ability to login, locally or remotely (so no password to manage)
- Ability for approved users to gain access to the screen session, and interact with the service.

I imagine the solution will have creative use of su/sudo and the details of how to create the account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create the account the `screen` session runs as (say it's called `screenimage`), as well as a group of users allowed to use it (say `screenusers`):

```
adduser --system --group screenimage
addgroup --system screenusers
```

Then for each user allowed to use it, add them to the `screenusers` group:

```
adduser USER screenusers
```

Then, add approved users to `/etc/sudoers`: run `visudo` and add the line

```
%screenusers ALL = (screenimage) /usr/bin/screen
```

ETA: To address the other answers on this post: the `--system` creates accounts with no shell or password. The `sudoers` line means that the users are clamped to running `screen`, as the `screenimage` user only.

Comment: +1 for actually using the tools the way they're intended.

Comment: nice tip about --system, being doing stuff like this for so long that this didn't used to be there :)

Comment: I presume the clamp to 'screen' is notional, if the daemon permits spawning of other processes?

Comment: For completeness, what command should an approved user issue to gain access to the screen session?

Answer (score 2):

Creating the user is the easy part. Simply add a user with adduser script (this is debian specific but I noticed it's in your tags) then edit the resulting /etc/passwd line for that user. Change the `x` to a `!` this makes it so that no password will ever match as valid. Change `/bin/bash` to `/bin/false`so that if someone did log in as this user they would get no shell.

As for the rest it really depends on what service you're trying to run or how you need to interact with it. I feel like there's probably some better way to work that out than running it in a screen session.

Comment: The service is a lisp image, which it is important to have interactive access to.

Comment: ok, but make sure that there's no way for an interactive user of the lisp image to spawn further processes...

Comment: I don't mind or care what the user can do inside the lisp image - I just don't want to manage a login password for this user.

Answer (score 1):

OK, how about (in /etc/rc.something):

```
sudo -u user screen -d -m service
```

and set *user's* shell to `/bin/false`.